# Different Template for Configurable Products

Tags: attributes, template, configurable-product

Totally stuck here. I'm working with a very customized template and the configurable products are just showing up in the bottom of the product page. I would like to change this and other things (remove a couple of attributes that are being shown for Simple products that I Do not want to show up if it is a configurable product and vice versa).

How do I go about to doing this? I tried searching in google and maybe I'm wording it incorrectly but.. no solutions yet. Is the a php code that I can use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options.

1. Magento offers a special layout handle for each type of product that is loaded for the product view page. For configurable products the handle is `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>`.
   You can use that to add or remove blocks using this handle
2. Create a new theme for the configurable products. This involves a little more work when adding a new configurable product. You need to create a new theme that defaults to your current theme and just add layout files and templates for your configurable products. Then you have to select your new theme in the `Design` tab for field `Custom Design` for all configurable products. You can do that using the `Update attributes` mass action in the products grid.

There is also a third option, to fill your templates with `if` statements to check if the product is configurable or not, but I don't recommend that.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I actually did try to use this on my catalog.xml file :  <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view2.phtml"> - but it's not working ;( and it's not showing up. Am I doing it incorrectly?