# custom view.phtml for configurable product

Tags: layout, configurable-product, magento-1, template

i want to call custom view.phtml page for configurable product

i wrote below code in local.xml

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left-configurable.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

what else changes have i to made to make it work

Answer (score 3):

Create a `local.xml`. 
then In the `local.xml` file, add this code:

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>custompage.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 3):

You already changed the page layout (the template for the `root` block). Now you need to change the template for the `product.info` block, which renders the `view.phtml`, in the same layout handle:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>your/custom/view.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to change view.phtml  you can use `content` reference name in your above xml code. As it would be like

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" as="product_info"  template="catalog/product/view/configurable_product.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

you can see detail answer by [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/different-template-for-configurable-products), i am sure it would very helpful to you.